# Class Not Found error in file upload using magento admin product csv upload

Tags: magento

Error: Class "Zend_Validate_File_Upload" not found in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-import-export/Model/Source/Upload.php:81 magento 2.4.6

please look the error and help me to sort out it.

I was just trying to product csv upload using magento admin.